# Not connected. Call Connect or wait for onConnected() to be called exception inside onConnected?

Tags: android, location, google-client

I have this `onConnected` call back implemented for `Google LocationClient API`:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    if (lc != null) {
        lastKnownLocation = lc.getLastLocation();
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        request.setFastestInterval(MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_UPDATES);
        request.setSmallestDisplacement(MIN_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_LOCATION_UPDATES);
        lc.requestLocationUpdates(request, ll);
    }
}
```

And for some reason, sometimes this line:

```
lastKnownLocation = lc.getLastLocation();
```

Gives me this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.de.bc()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ez.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ez$c.bc()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ey.getLastLocation()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.ez.getLastLocation()
   at com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.getLastLocation()
   at com.citylifeapps.cups.helputils.UserLocation.onConnected(UserLocation.java:115)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.de.aZ()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.de$f.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.de$f.a()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.de$b.be()
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.de$a.handleMessage()
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I really can't understand why this happens. Clearly I'm trying to get the last known location using the `LocationClient` after running the connect method and waiting for the `onConnected` callback and as I understand the `onConnected` call back is called when I have connection, So how can I get the `"Not connected ..."` exception?
Does some one knows?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what happens here already?

Comment: Hi Emil Adz, Did you resolved this issue? Me too facing same issue last two days. If you resolved, Please help me how can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like me, you did not call connect() at all. Try with the call included in the onStart method:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: Yup. Android doc forgot to mention you should connect. TT_TT

Comment: This is absolutely true and still not corrected in the Android docs. Following the tutorial 1:1 will fail you!

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue on Samsung S4 and S3 mini.

Just wrap with try/catch getLastLocation() and start to getting actual location from requirstLocationUpdate:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    if (lc != null) {
        try{   
           lastKnownLocation = lc.getLastLocation();
        catch(Exception ex){ /* log error */ }

        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        request.setFastestInterval(MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_LOCATION_UPDATES);
        request.setSmallestDisplacement(MIN_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_LOCATION_UPDATES);
        lc.requestLocationUpdates(request, ll);
    }
}
```

Comment: No it's not that simple, wrapping this line with try and catch may remove the crashes but a lot of my users complain on the location detection problems. So this does not solve my problem.

Comment: usually it crashed on getting last location only but you can get actual location.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Log.w(TAG, "onConnected");
    if (!mLocationClient.isConnecting()) {
        mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    }
}
```

So far it works fine for me but I have absolutely no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but just in case someone stumbles into this problem, too. In my case, I got the same error message as Emil. After some debugging I noticed that (in my specific code) I called mLocationClient.connect() twice, the second time with a little delay of approx. 100 milliseconds. I believe the first call caused the onConnect() callback to be triggered, but then the second connect() call broke the connection.

The solution in my case was to check before connecting, if there is not already a connection, similar as Extended Range suggests it above. I'm not sure why Google disconnects the mLocationClient on a repeated connect() call, but in my case it solved the problem.

```
if (!mLocationClient.isConnected() && !mLocationClient.isConnecting()){
    mLocationClient.connect();
}
```